# Drawing in Custom ScrollView

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

I'm trying to draw in a scrollview on top of an image using multi-touch.  The circles are actually drawn, but under the image. In my code I currently create a custom ScrollView:

@interface AppScrollView : UIScrollView {

```
//objects to draw circles
NSMutableDictionary *circlesInProcess;
NSMutableArray *completeCircles;
```

}

@end

In my AppScrollView.m I override touches commands to store touches and add a

```
    (void)drawRect:(CGRect) rect
```

method to draw the circles in the scrollview.  I also include

```
    [self setNeedsDisplay]
```

to display the circles.  In my app controller, I declare the new custom scrollView object:

```
    IBOutlet AppScrollView *scrollView;
```

Later I add an image to the scrollView using:

```
    [scrollView addSubview:myImage];
```

The image is visible, but when I try to draw circles on top of it, they are drawn under the image.  Let me know if you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: draw the image onto your scrollview (instead of adding the image view as a subview) and then draw the circles on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

In your code check where did you add you custom scrollview. Is it added after imageView is added or before.

You scrollView should be on top of imageView.

Comment: He's adding the imageview to the scrollview as a subview, so the image will obscure anything drawn directly on the scrollview, no matter what order in which things are added.

Comment: aah ok i misunderstood the first line.. but still addSubview works in sequence right ? so if you add image than draw circles after that the circles should be added on top, no ?

Comment: I think they're maintained as two separate layers/windows, so the image will always obscure whatever's drawn underneath it.

Comment: custom scrollView was added in interface builder using class name of custom UIScrollView.  The ImageView was added in code to the custom scrollview.  I'm guessing that I need to create a custom UIImageView, but the class does not accept a <UIImageViewDelegate> as the ScrollView class does.  Thanks!